# Установка ImageMagick на OpenServer

Tags: php, openserver, imagemagick, imagick

Кто знает как использовать ImageMagick в OpenServer?
Скачал OpenServer вместе с ImageMagick, но при попытке им воспользоваться выдает ошибку 
**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Imagick' not found in C:\OSPanel\domains\imagick.loc\index.php:2 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\OSPanel\domains\imagick.loc\index.php on line 2**

```
<?$im = new Imagick("one.psd");
```

Comment: Класс Imagick не существует, скачайте OpenServer с официльного ресурса

Comment: На хабре есть прекрасный мануал: [тык](https://habr.com/ru/sandbox/58371/)

Comment: убедитесь, что расширение включено в конфиге

Comment: Расширение в конфиге включено, дело в том, что при перезапуске сервера строчка "extension=php_imagick.dl" удаляется из php.ini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Переключил версию php с 7.1 на 5.6, все работает. На версии 5.6 уже установлен imagick и возиться с ним не надо. Выше версии 5.6, imagick так и не получилось запустить.